# Next-ing from child each loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this bit of code:

```
gates.each do |key, value, temp|
  unless value.class == Output
    temp = value.in1
    gates.each do |k, v|
      if v.out == temp
        value.base_distance += 1
        #do a thing
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to happen is when the `#do a thing` comment inside the conditional is reached it should break out of the inner .each loop and move on to the next instance of the outer .each loop, essentially executing a `next`. How would I do that from inside the conditional?

Comment: Why does `gates.each` have three block variables in the outer loop but only two in the inner loop?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What is the code supposed to achieve?

Comment: Wesley, you don't like answering questions?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** use [`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement).

Here is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
[1,2].each do |o|
  puts "Outer: #{o}"
  [1,2,3].each do |i|
    break if i.even?
    puts "Inner: #{i}"
  end
end

#⇒ Outer: 1
#  Inner: 1
#  Outer: 2
#  Inner: 1
```

---

FWIW, one might pass an argument to break to be returned from the block. This might be needed to emulate the `next` after `break`:

```
[1,2].each do |o|
  puts "Outer: #{o}"

  inner =
    [1,2,3].each do |i|
      break :next if i.even?
      puts "Inner: #{i}"
    end
  next if inner == :next
  ...
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still execute code that is after the inner loop?

Comment: I mentioned one might pass the argument to `break` and from your question, it was not clear what you actually wanted to achieve. I have updated the answer.